# Add programmatically a scrollable linear layout

Tags: android, scrollable

I've this layout file and the java code.

I need to create a horizontally scrollable linear layout to scroll over the buttons.
In this way it doesn't scroll at all.

```xml
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/questionListSV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/questionList_LL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

```java
for (int i =0; i<maxQuestionNo;i++) {
    Button qbtn = new Button(mContext);
    qbtn.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1));
    ll.addView(qbtn);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) instead of ScrollView

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/questionListSV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/questionList_LL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Only link answers are normally deleted, you should add at least an example.

Comment: @OneWay why should link answers be deleted if they provide enough informations (you always need to five details in case your link gets broken)

Comment: @AIL http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer